# Printing collapsed css divs

Tags: css

I am using the following to run some expanding/collapsing divs

```
<div class="FAQ">
    <a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1">+</a>
    <a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1">-</a>
    <div class="question"> Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question Question? </div>
        <div class="list">
            <p>Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* source: http://www.ehow.com/how_12214447_make-collapsing-lists-java.html */

.FAQ { 
    vertical-align: top; 
    height:auto !important; 
}
.list {
    display:none; 
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
}
.show {
    display: none; 
}
.hide:target + .show {
    display: inline; 
}
.hide:target {
    display: none; 
}
.hide:target ~ .list {
    display:inline; 
}
```

as found (and continued) here [Pure CSS collapse/expand div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095933/pure-css-collapse-expand-div/19686754#19686754)

My issue is that I can't get my expanded div to print either using Ctrl+p or using a function printpage script.

I am new to this kind of thing and I feel the answer must be staring me in the face. Is there something I can add to my print.css file to force it to at least ignore the funcitonality of the class FAQ and print all that is hidden if I can't get it to print just the expanded div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This Link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) might help you

Answer (score 3):

The best way to ignore the functionality of your expand/collapse is to just expand the answer divs through the styling in your print.css.

```
    .list {
        display: inline;
    }
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I can't work out why it doesn't work!! I am going to sleep on it and post again in the morning (UK Time)

Answer (score 1):

I added the above line in **print.css**:

```
.list {
    display: inline;
}
```

and also did the following:

```
<div id="div0" class="collapse changethis">                                
<div class="panel-body" float="right" id="print_content">
<table class="table details" style="margin-left: -390px;margin-top:20px;" id="485">                                
<tbody>
<tr><th>Product name</th>                                
<th>HSN Code</th>                              
<th>Amount</th>                                
</tr>
<tr><td>Backlight Flex</td>
<td> 212223</td>
<td>5000</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Flex Printing</td>
<td>39219090</td>
<td>900</td>
</tr>                                
</tbody>
</table>                                
</div>                                 
</div>
```

script

```
    <script>
    function print_page()
    {
         var printContents = document.getElementById("print_content").innerHTML;
         var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
         document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
         //expand collapsible divs
         $('div.changethis').addClass('in').css("height", "");
         window.print();
         document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
         window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('clients/search'); ?>";   
    }
</script>
```

PS- above mentioned code is only a small part of my working module, i have shown only some parts for easy readability and understandability.

The line below:

`//expand collapsible divs
  $('div.changethis').addClass('in').css("height", "");`

worked its magic.

[Link to the fiddle that i referred](https://jsfiddle.net/j2dneers/)