# Primefaces component which allows hiding a trailing part of the text, but never all of it

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm looking for a Primefaces component which allows a variable trailing part of a text, but never all of it to be hidden, e.g.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula
eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et [...](clickable)
```

which then expands to

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula
eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.[less](clickable)
```

and back.

I know that this could be easily done with an output label, a backing bean and a `commandLink`, but why reinvent the wheel.

I'm using Primefaces 6.0 in a Java EE 7 application.

Comment: Because there is no component in the PrimeFaces library that does it?

Comment: Or without a commandLink and just a link and some javascript and wrap al; thatbin a composite component

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, and from looking at the PrimeFaces doco there is no standard component.

@see [Pure CSS collapse/expand div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095933/pure-css-collapse-expand-div)

Is probably a better solution, remember if u want styling - PrimeFaces just uses the JQuery UI classes.